# Tuple as Key for ets table?

Tags: erlang, ets

I want to store tuples regarding information on other network participants in an ETS table. 
I would like to use a tuple of `{ip_address(), port_number()}` (return of `inet:peername(Socket)` as the key of the entries. Aka I want to use the combination of address / port as an identifier for the other nodes / entries in the ETS table.

Is this possible with ets? Or do I have to use an other type as a key?

Comment: You mean like `ets:insert(Table, {{"127.0.0.1", 4000}, value}).`? That seems to be working fine.

Comment: More like `ets:insert(Table, {{{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}, 4000}, value}).`. It does seem to work fine for me, too. I however recently got some strange errors and could not find information on whether one could use tuples. I could imagine maybe erlang gets confused which of the nested tuples it should regard as key.

Comment: This should also be fine. Maybe add some relevant code and the exact error you get.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ETS stands for "Erlang Term Storage" and it can store any Erlang term, including tuples and tuples of tuples. The description section of [the `ets` man page](http://erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html) details how terms are compared and matched for particular table types, and the documentation for [`ets:lookup/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#lookup-2) discusses this as well. For some table types, [Erlang term order](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id81064) is important.

There is no confusion regarding which part of a stored tuple is the key; the [`ets:new/2` function](http://erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#new-2), used to create a table, includes the `{keypos, Pos}` option to indicate the key element. If `{keypos, Pos}` is not provided, the first element is the key.

Comment: ***ETS stands for "Erlang Term Storage" and it can store any Erlang term, including tuples...***--From the [ets docs](http://erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html): *Data is organized as a set of dynamic tables, which can store tuples*. -- And from [LYSE](https://learnyousomeerlang.com/ets): *All ETS tables natively store Erlang tuples containing whatever you want, where one of the tuple elements will act as a primary key..*--It sounds like the ONLY data type that ets can store is a tuple (with any other data type inside the tuple).  Is that true?

Comment: Regarding the table storage, yes, it's all tuples. But what the tuple means to the user of the table differs. In one case, the tuple being stored is the whole value that's meaningful to the user; e.g., if the tuple is really a record, then the whole record is the value the user is interested in, and one field is the key. The other case involves keys and values that are distinct but are explicitly paired into a tuple only because that's what ets requires. This case includes values that are their own keys explicitly placed inside tuples only to satisfy ets, such as `{42}` or `{"foo"}`.